# Pyomo nonlinear constraint to linear

Tags: python, linear-programming, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to linearize an equation by using logarithms to calculate the heat generation of a battery (q_batt).

I have lots of code from the open source software oemof (oemof.readthedocs.io) and this part is where my problem is:

```
    def _q_batt_first_rule(block, n, t):
        current = m.flow[n, i[n], t] / n.inflow_voltage
        expr = 0
        expr += block.q_batt[n, t] - n.inflow_resistance(block.capacity[n, t]) * current**2
        return expr == 0
    self.q_bat_first_rule = Constraint(self.STORAGES, reduced_timesteps,
                                       rule=_q_batt_first_rule)
```

The original equation is:

```
q_batt = inflow_resistance * (inflow_flow / inflow_voltage)^2
```

And I want to rewrite it as linear to be able to solve it with the CBC solver

inflow_resistance (n.inflow_resistance(block.capacity[n, t])) is an input linear equation that depends on capacity (which is a variable calculated in the battery object - called block), inflow_flow (m.flow[n, i[n], t]) is calculated in the model and voltage_in (n.inflow_voltage) is an input constant

Do you know how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Pyomo code has `log(1 / n.inflow_voltage)` which is missing a square. Note that `log(1/x^2) = -2log(x)`

Comment: True, thank you, I corrected it. It is still considered nonlinear however, n.inflow_voltage is just an input constant

Comment: Sure, `log(x)` is nonlinear. I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to linearize `q_batt = inflow_resistance * (inflow_flow / inflow_voltage)^2`, maybe there is a way... I need to use a linear solver

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: @AlbaVilanova, your question might be better suited for [Math Stack Exhange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will post it there too, thank you :)